# Get DropDown value using its name in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these `SELECT`s in my page

```
 <select id="select_status_id44" name="select_status_id[44]" class="inputbox" id =      "status_id_44">
<option value="1">Pending</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Confirmed</option>
<option value="3">Cancelled</option>
<option value="4">Refunded</option>
<option value="5">Shipped</option>
<option value="6">Paid</option>
<option value="7">Complete</option>
</select>
```

And also this one

```
 <select id="select_status_id78" name="select_status_id[78]" class="inputbox" id =      "status_id_44">
<option value="1">Pending</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Confirmed</option>
<option value="3">Cancelled</option>
<option value="4">Refunded</option>
<option value="5">Shipped</option>
<option value="6">Paid</option>
<option value="7">Complete</option>
</select>
```

I want to do is that whenever any of these two SELECT is CHANGED, it shoul dget the select_status_id[`ID`]  ID inside that tag...

For now I have simply done this but it does not work

```
$('select[name=select_status_id]').change(function() {    
    alert('dsada');
});
```

I know that I should not get using ID attribute because they are different for both ... but NAME attribute is same

Comment: where is your `select` with `name=order_check_id`.

Comment: @Mritunjay sorry ,,, wdited qs ... that name-select_status_id

Answer (score 2):

You can try this on change for each select.

```
$("#select_status_id44").change(function(){
    var val = "select_status_id["+$(this).val()+"]";
    $(this).prop("name", val);
    console.log(val);
});
```

**UPDATE:** Check this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/L8TWN/1

Comment: I cant do this .... then what about select_status_id55 and select_status_id66 or others????

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis. Corrected it. Now its working. See fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/L8TWN/1/)... AND you have to do this for each select.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$('select[name^="select_status_id"]').change(function() {    
    alert($(this).attr('name').split('[')[1].replace(']',''));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LpaRE/1/)

Comment: There are other SELECTS are as well with same class .... I want to get it via NAME

Comment: This works over there but not in my code ... 

I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " in CONSOLE ... I am using Joomla 2.5 and have added the JQuery inside the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

if you can add a data-property to your select

```
<select data-id-value="42" ..... >
```

---

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    console.log ( $(this).data('id-value') );
});
```